# how do I download and install the wireless card driver for a Toshiba a215 laptop?

Tags: wireless, drivers

I have been searching for a while on how to do this, but am unable to get anywhere. Here is the wireless card I have:

```
*-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: AR5001 Wireless Network Adapter
                vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:14:00.0
                logical name: wlan0
                version: 01
                serial: 00:1b:9e:bd:23:2c
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath5k driverversion=2.6.38-11-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg
                resources: irq:19 memory:f8200000-f820ffff
```

Answer (score 1):

Your trace looks like the output of `sudo lshw -class Network` - as such the kernel has already recognised your wireless card and you most probably dont need to download any drivers.

Try the following suggested fix:

Run the following in a terminal:

```
sudo rmmod -f ath5k
sudo rfkill unblock all
sudo modprobe ath5k
```

Then restart your network connection

```
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

[source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1726035)